# BMC150 initialization does not work

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f10x, stm32f103c8t6

I am trying to read ID register of BMC150 using SPI. I am using stm32f103 microcontroller. Serial clock line is OK and the data is sent properly over MOSI of microcontroller. But no response is sent back through MISO. I have checked signals using oscilloscope. Here is a part of my C code. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks.

```
    while(1){
    //Activate Slave
    SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    // Go to active power mode
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4B01);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
    // delay for applying setting stably
    delay_ms(1);
    // Go to normal mode
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4C00);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
    delay_ms(1);
    // read request
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0xC000);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE)));
    while (SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY));
    }
```

Comment: Is the CS pin low?

Comment: Did you *measure* this with the scope or a multimeter? That line says nothing since we don't see the value of `SPI_PIN_SS`. There is a really good chance this line does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Dear @TurboJ , You are right, I wil check it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by activating and deactivating slave (using chip or slave select pin) before and after writing process as follows:

```
while(1){
//Activate Slave
SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
// Go to active power mode
SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4B01);
while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
SPI_GPIO->BSRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
// delay for applying setting stably
delay_ms(1);
SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
// Go to normal mode
SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4C00);
while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
SPI_GPIO->BSRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
delay_ms(1);
```